# Set max number of rows to read in read_xls in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I am using `readxl::read_xls()` in **R**.

I have an xls file where the data I need to read starts in cell `J3`. The data goes until cell `DX`, but the number of rows always differs.

I would like to set the range to read my xls file from cell `J3` until the last observation in cell `DX`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` parameter in `read_xls` is handled by the cellranger package and lets you set more general limits on the range to read. In your case:

```
readxl::read_xls('./test.xls', range = cell_limits(c(3, 4), c(NA, 10)))
```

This will read from `D3` to `JX`, where `X` is the last row with data.